# How can I use both Laravel and Drupal in my website?

Tags: php, laravel, drupal-7, integration

I have a website build in Drupal 7. Due to complexity of some pages I want to build those pages in framework like Laravel!
Can I do that?
I want to keep user login and some node functionality of Drupal and will use Drupal's db!

Comment: If your Drupal site has API, you call the API in Laravel application, else you have to do a thorough integration job to make both work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but you shouldn't. The Drupal and Laravel are both back-end frameworks. By keeping some part of Drupal and another from Laravel will create problems for you later if not now. Just for example, you will have to sync session management of both systems to keep things synced!

Rather, I would suggest you go for some Front-End frameworks like BackBone, Angular etc. It'll effectively work with Drupal, as Drupal provides the REST API support.