# Access laravel 5.0 session values from drupal 7

Tags: laravel-5, drupal-7, session-variables

I am trying to get access laravel 5.0 session values for drupal 7.
I have put a value into laravel session using `session(['test' => 'Hello']);` or `Session::put('test', 'abc');`. And then how can I get this value from laravel session in drupal 7?

Comment: We can't help without more information , laravel is used into drupal 7 or it's separate instance?

Comment: @Fky I use laravel folder inside drupal folder as a separate folder. For example, /var/www/html/drupal-7/laravel-5.0. And I write redirect rule in .htaccess file of drupal to redirect to laravel.

Comment: Why ? it's a bad thing to modify core htaccess , you will create potencial security issues. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765616/how-can-i-use-both-laravel-and-drupal-in-my-website